# How to make no statement if not show hostname - gethostbyaddr

Tags: php, gethostbyaddr

I try to make simple php script to show hostname using gethostbyaddr. Let pretend the ip xxx.xxx.xxx.4 will show the hostname and ip xxx.xxx.xxx.5 not show hostname. My question is, how do i make if no hostname statement? Thank you.

```
$ips = array("xxx.xxx.xxx.4","xxx.xxx.xxx.5");

foreach ($ips as $value) {
    if ($hostip = @gethostbyaddr( $value )) {
       echo "$hostip<br>";
    }   
    else {
       //show no hostname statement here
    }
}
```

Comment: you're question is unclear.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `gethostbyaddr()` returns the original IP if no host was found, so you can compare it back to `$value`

Comment: Hi @LatheesanKanes. Actually, i want to make table of ip and it will show the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/gethostbyaddr):

> Returns the host name on success, the unmodified ip_address on failure, or FALSE on malformed input.

So you could do this:

```
<?php
    $ips = array("xxx.xxx.xxx.4","xxx.xxx.xxx.5");

    foreach ($ips as $value) {
        $hostname = gethostbyaddr($value);

        if ($hostname === false) { //malformed input
            echo 'IP "' . $value . '" was malformed<br />';
        } else if ($hostname === $value) { //failure
            echo 'Hostname could not be found for "' . $value . '"<br />';
        } else { //success
            echo 'Hostname: ' . $hostname . '<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```